# What's the difference between went +verb and verb?

Tags: word-usage

What's the difference between went shopping and shopped in the following sentences:

> 1 I went shopping yesterday.

> 2 I shopped yesterday.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I went shopping yesterday.

emphasises you had to move somewhere in order to do your shopping.

> I shopped yesterday.

just describes the action of browsing, choosing items and paying for them.

Both are grammatically correct, the former is definitely natural, but I haven't heard the latter much.

Comment: Yes. I think "I shopped" isn't as common. But it's very usual to say "I shopped for food, groceries, etc." or I like to shop at "some place" for clothes. That doesn't deny the fact that "I shopped yesterday" is not natural. It is rather a matter of context. e.g. "As I shopped/was shopping yesterday, I made a new friend."